# How to read Java files in workspace from a Jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath

I have this weird scenario where I let the client edit few classes in his workspace. I have an executable jar that he will place inside the project's lib folder. In one of the menus, it should call the java classes that the client has edited in his workspace.

How can I make the Jar call the Java classes in the workspace?

Answer (score 2):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/path/to/java", "-cp", "packagename.Class"); 
pb.directory(new File("preferred/working/directory"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

This works with main method.

Or:

```
InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("c:/..../TestClass.class");
byte rawBytes[] = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
fileInputStream.read(rawBytes); 

Class<?> regeneratedClass = this.defineClass("testpack.TestClass",rawBytes, 0, rawBytes.length);                    

System.out.println(regeneratedClass.getMethod("getSimpleMethod", null).invoke(regeneratedClass.newInstance(), null));
```

Comment: I dont want to execute the Jar from java file. My jar is already an executable jar. Client just double clicks it and the UI will open. In one of the menu, he clicks something and that should call the class from the user's workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is pretty weird; you should really consider a different design.

When the customer is running the code in eclipse: it might enough to check the "run" configuration that your customer is using. There is a "Classpath" tab - you could use that to specify that the classes that are compiled locally have precedence over the JAR that gave to the customer.

If he is running your application from the command line, then you have to provide a corresponding classpath - making sure that those "local overrides" come in front of the JAR that contains the "older" versions of the classes.

As an alternative, you could provide build scripts/guidance that allows to customer to build a repackaged JAR file.

EDIT:

Would it be possible that you provide your JAR file **without** the classes that are supposed to come from the customer? If the classes only exist in the customer workspace ... at least you dont have to worry about which version of the classes will be used (as there is only one version of them!)

Comment: actually he just double clicks the executable jar that I provide. Inside the jar, one class will call the client's class (the one present in workspace). I need to write code which goes inside the jar, so that it will read the files in workspace.

Comment: @naveenbharadwaj I am not sure if that can be done. You can use  the JAR manifest file to manipulate the class path ( see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html ), **but** I am not sure if it is possible to ensure that these additional class path elements have **precedence** over the classes in the JAR. (and that is your problem right now: it doesn't matter if the customer has newer class files - if the classloader is searching inside the JAR first, it will always load the classes from there.